# Unable to update extension outside of google chrome extension market

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to update an extension that I have developed which has been installed by policy because I do not have it in the extensions market.

This is the content of my updates.xml file which is accessible through the link in my extension's manifest.json.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'>
    <app appid='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'>
        <updatecheck codebase='https://myserver.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/download' version='0.8' />
    </app>
</gupdate>
```

On previous occasions, by modifying the updates.xml file, the extension was updated without problems, but now it seems to be not enough.

I have read that now Google Chrome does not support updates outside the extension market by default. What do I have to do to update my extension?